# Any idea how to add in a table for my wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, reactjs

I'm currently working on a custom table box for wordpress. I already have a custom made plugin and some javascript code, but it's mostly copied and I cant figure out how to convert it into a table (when I use the plugin, I can only add in plain text and it has a coloured box around it). It would be really nice if someone could figure it out for me.

heres some code

```
function updateContent(event) {
  props.setAttributes({content: event.target.value})
}
function updateColor(value) {
  props.setAttributes({color: value.hex})
}
return React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement(
    "h3",
    null,
    "Simple Box"
  ),
  React.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: props.attributes.content, onChange: updateContent }),
  React.createElement(wp.components.ColorPicker, { color: props.attributes.color, onChangeComplete: updateColor })
);
```

Thats basically where all the magic happens
(dont know why its cropped so weird)

Comment: What's up with that code? Why is it returning outside a function? Why is it using React to create elements? And what exactly is a table box? Can you give examples of desired input and output?

Comment: As I said most of it is copied, but I assume it's using react, because it creates a "box" on a wordpress page. A Table box is nothing else than just a table with rows and collumns and it's called box, because thats how its called in wordpress and the only output is basically the front end of the page.